# Mysql table on Excel sheet?

Tags: mysql, excel

I am using Windows7 and Microsoft office 2010 and mysql5. I want to connect Microsoft excel with my database mysql. I have installed all the drivers. I have created a data source as well. I am going step-by-step to connect, but at the end when i click on test connections, I receive this error message

> Test connection failed because of error in intializing provider unspecified error.

Comment: we need to know what steps you followed.... I guess you forgot to add Data Sources(ODBC)

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not using the right ODBC driver.

Please check if you downloaded the one that matches your MySQL database. (not only version number, but especially if it is a 32-bit server or a 64-bit server).